# Unable to reinstall or uninstall broken brew package(didn't delete anything)

Tags: macos, homebrew

```
brew cask install android-sdk
```

> Warning: A Cask for android-sdk is already installed.

```
brew cask reinstall android-sdk
```

or

```
brew cask uninstall android-sdk
```

```
==> Caveats We will install android-sdk-tools, platform-tools, and build-tools for you. You can control android sdk packages via the
sdkmanager command. You may want to add to your profile:   'export
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk'

This operation may take up to 10 minutes depending on your internet
connection. Please, be patient.

==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip
Already downloaded:
/Users/ishandutta2007/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/android-sdk--25.2.3.zip
==> Verifying checksum for Cask android-sdk Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/share/android-sdk Follow the instructions here:
https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask#reporting-bugs
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1439:in
`unlink'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1439:in
`block in remove_file'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1444:in
`platform_support'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1438:in
`remove_file'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:785:in
`remove_file'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:563:in
`block in rm'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:562:in
`each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:562:in
`rm'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cask_loader.rb:57:in
`block (2 levels) in load'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/artifact/abstract_flight_block.rb:35:in
`instance_eval'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/artifact/abstract_flight_block.rb:35:in
`block in abstract_phase'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb:232:in
`each_key'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb:232:in
`each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/artifact/abstract_flight_block.rb:34:in
`abstract_phase'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/artifact/abstract_flight_block.rb:28:in
`uninstall_phase'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/installer.rb:330:in
`block in uninstall_artifacts'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/installer.rb:327:in
`each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/installer.rb:327:in
`uninstall_artifacts'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/installer.rb:312:in
`uninstall'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/reinstall.rb:27:in
`block in install_casks'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/reinstall.rb:6:in
`each'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/reinstall.rb:6:in
`install_casks'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/install.rb:10:in
`run' /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli.rb:115:in
`run_command'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli.rb:158:in
`process' /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/cask.rb:8:in `cask'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:91:in `<main>'
```

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32895800/cant-reinstall-or-uninstall-homebrew-after-blowing-away-contents-of-usr-local) but no luck, and I have not deleted anything like mentioned in this question.

Comment: I got my issue sorted by installing via AndroidStudio and then setting ANDROID_HOME and PATH variable as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19986294/865220, but the question should remain open as I couldn't get it working using homebrew

Comment: [brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/android-sdk) recommends tu use `brew install --cask android-sdk`

Answer (score 15):

I observed no such directory `/usr/local/share/android-sdk` as the error stated:

```
$ sudo find /usr -name "android-sdk"
/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk
```

I also ran into these errors:

```
Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/usr/local/bin/adb'; not linking.
Error: It seems there is already a Binary at '/usr/local/bin/fastboot'; not linking.
```

I deleted the mentioned files and then was able to install:

```
$ rm -rf /usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk
$ rm -rf /usr/local/bin/adb
$ rm -rf /usr/local/bin/fastboot
$ brew cask install android-sdk
```

Comment: this worked for me for docker as well! `brew install docker --cask` -> `  docker was successfully installed!` 

Comment: For me, I needed `rm -r /opt/homebrew/share/fish/vendor_completions.d/docker.fish; rm -r /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_docker; rm -f /opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/docker`, then `brew install --cask docker` was successful.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to install that package cleanly, you'll have to remove the broken stuff previously

```
brew doctor
brew cleanup
```

then you can proceed installing the package.

Manually removing binaries is not recommended, homebrew already does that for you and it knows exactly what to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue after the recent relocation of android-sdk into caskroom/cask managed to break one of my install scripts. I ended up fixing it by manually messing around directly with the cask-installed directories (/usr/local/share/android-sdk, /usr/local/opt/android-sdk, and so on). I either deleted what was there or created empty directories, then re-running the remove/reinstall/delete commands finally worked. Sorry I can't be more specific, but it was basically a case of getting my directories to look like brew expected them to look.